# Javafx slider ends before media

Tags: javafx, slider, vlcj

I have a runnable that updates slider position every second but the slider reaches end before media that it is supposed to control. How do I set it up so it ends in the same time?

```
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateRunnable(mediaPlayer), 0L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 private final class UpdateRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private UpdateRunnable(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            System.out.println("Not playing");
            return;
        }  
        final long time = this.mediaPlayer.getTime();
        final int position = (int)(this.mediaPlayer.getPosition() * 1000.0f);

        mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void positionChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newPosition) {
            currentPosition = newPosition;
        }
        });

        time_counter++;
        System.out.println("New Position is " + currentPosition);
        System.out.println("New time is " + time_counter);
        // Updates to user interface components must be executed on the Event
        // Dispatch Thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    //System.out.println("time = " + time);
                    updateTime(time);
                    updatePosition(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void updatePosition(int value) {
    timeSlider.setValue(value);
}
```

Is there anyway how can I set slider's length based on the length of the media being played?

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the number of seconds the media has been playing? If so, I would bind my `Slider` to that property and divided by the total number of seconds in the media.

Comment: I am using Vlcj libraries to play my media . I think there is a getTime() method that retrieves some type of time.

Comment: mediaPlayer.getTime() returns the number of milliseconds that the media has been playing. mediaPlayer.getPosition() returns the percentage complete (e.g. 0.25f for 25% complete). That should be all you need to scale your slider value according to the range you set.

Comment: I've tried mediaPlayer.getPosition() and in the end it went up to 1,25f. So I don't really understand. Does it represent 125% then?